# "Origin checking failed - null does not match any trusted origins"

Tags: python-3.x, django

I run two servers with two different PORTs on localhost. (localhost:3000 and localhost:4000)
I have a post form in localhost:3000 and want to send to localhost:4000

```
<form action = "http://localhost:4000/print" method = POST>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

in my views.py of localhost:4000

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        file = data.get("filename")
        return render(request,"print_success.html",{"form":file})
```

Error occurs:
`Origin checking failed - null does not match any trusted origins`
I don't know why there is `origin:null`

Already tried `cors-headers` set up